# Html CSS force to be always in the lowest part

Tags: html, css

I have the following html + css:

```
<!-- Here starts the header-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top  ">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> MEGA SERIES</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="/">Series</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a class="right-margin" href="/"></span> Iniciar sesion</a></li>
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="{% url 'series:search' %}" method="post">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search_text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de la serie">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Buscar
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <p class="lead">Buscar por categorías</p>
          <div class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item" <%= link_to "Comedia", category_path("Comedia") %></a>
            <a class="list-group-item" <%= link_to "Aventura", category_path("Aventura") %></a>
            <a class="list-group-item" <%= link_to "Drama", category_path("Drama") %></a>
            <a class="list-group-item" <%= link_to "Fantastico", category_path("Fantastico") %></a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-9">
        <% if flash[:from_add_product] %>
          <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>Se ha añadido al carrito correctamente!</strong>
          </div>
        <% end %>
          <div class="row">
              <% @series.each do |serie| %>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src=<%= serie.image %> alt="" style="height: 290px; width: 240px">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right price"><%= (serie.chapters.size * serie.chapters[0].price * 0.8).round(2)%> €</h4>
                            <h4> <%= link_to serie.title, season_path(serie) %> </h4>
                            <%=serie.plot%></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <br />
                            <p class="pull-right">Lanzamiento: <%= serie.release_year%></p>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <div class="buy">
                          <td><%= link_to "Comprar Serie", {:controller => "payments", :action => :addproduct, :item => serie}, {:method => :post, :class=>"btn btn-success"} %></td>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <% end %>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

```
<!-- Here starts page footer-->
<footer class="navbar-bottom">
   <p> Copyright © 2017 Mega Series España </a> </p>
</footer>

</html>


.navbar-bottom{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 1%;
   padding-bottom: 0.5%;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #2f2f2f;
   color: #ffffff;
 }
```

If the page has enough content it shows like this:

[image]

It is ok, it's in the lowest part and there isn't white space below.

But if the page doesn't have enough content that's how it looks:

[image]

There's white space below footer. What I can do to force it to be always in the lowest part?

Comment: look into position:fixed

Comment: Post your complete html and css please. There are a few ways of doing it, but it depends on the rest of your markup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Footer at bottom of browser except when I scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812551/footer-at-bottom-of-browser-except-when-i-scroll)

Comment: can you post rest of your code to solve your problem effectively

Comment: I've edited the post with all code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;`,`bottom:0px;` insted of `position: absolute;` It will always set the footer at bottom position.and don't move it when scrolled.

```
.navbar-bottom{
    position: fixed;
     bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    color: #ffffff;
 }
```

```css
 .navbar-bottom{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 1%;
   padding-bottom: 0.5%;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #2f2f2f;
   color: #ffffff;
   bottom:0px;
 }
```

```html
  <footer class="navbar-bottom">
    <p> Copyright © 2017 Mega Series España </a> </p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Same behaviour with fixed

Comment: and bottom:0px;

Comment: Still the same! It just places below series but not in the lowest part.

Comment: position:fixed,bottom:0px; will  make it stay at bottom of the page always.Eg:check the snippet.and what you mean by below the series?

Answer (score 0):

i think in css

```
  bottom:0
```

might work

Comment: It places below series but not in the lowest part!

Comment: try some negative value or height: 100% , do reply

Answer (score -1):

This is Thee CSS Rules

```
.footer {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       width: 100%;
      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      height: 60px;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
 }
```

Comment: Safari doesn't have inspect button, can you provide the css rules please?

Comment: Please don't submit link only answers. Either provide an actual code solution in your answer, or leave this as a comment to OP's post.

Comment: Sorry @Michael Coker